OpenAI ServiceConnect for `chat` completion API does not properly implement `logprobs` option
According to the OpenAI ServiceConnect documentation, the Chat request supports the option LogProbs (which allows for specifying a number of tokens for which to obtain log-probabilities, as described in the OpenAI documentation.  However, as of 02 April 2024 in Mathematica 14.0, it appears to be broken.
The (deprecated) completion service connection works OK:
ServiceExecute["OpenAI", "Completion",
  {"Prompt" -> "Do bears defecate in the forest? Answer only True or False and nothing else.",
   "LogProbs" -> 2}];
%[[1, "logprobs", "top_logprobs", 2]]
(* <|"True" -> -0.00109212, "False" -> -7.53893|> *)

But the completion API is deprecated, and not supported by the currently recommended models:
ServiceExecute["OpenAI", "Completion",
 {"Prompt" -> "Do bears defecate in the forest? Answer only True or False and nothing else.",
  "LogProbs" -> 2,
  "Model" -> "gpt-3.5-turbo"}]
(* ServiceExecute::apierr: The service returned the following error message: This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?. *)

The current chat-completion API is supported as the "Chat" request type in ServiceConnect, but appears not to support the "LogProbs" option stated in the documentation:
ServiceExecute["OpenAI", "Chat",
 {"Messages" -> {
    <|"Role" -> "User",
     "Content" -> "Do bears defecate in the forest? Answer only True or False and nothing else."|>},
  "LogProbs" -> 2}]
(* ServiceExecute::noget: The parameter logprobs is not available for the service OpenAI. *) 


hesitating to use the "b" word (bug)...but at least an apparent discrepancy between documentation and implementation

It is still marked as "Experimental", so some troubles here and there are expected :) But surely you can report this to the WRI.

Perhaps this might be useful to you: Live CEOing #780. For example, there is undocumented "RawChat".

Alas:  "RawChat" in 14.0 restricts keywords (rather than passing them through as @SWolfram suggests in the Live CEOing video), so that is not a workaround.

The new Mathematica 14.1 release does not fix this in the OpenAI Chat service:
ServiceExecute["OpenAI", "Chat", 
   {"Messages" -> {<|
       "Role" -> "User", 
       "Content" -> "Do bears defecate in the forest? Answer only True or False and nothing else."|>},
  "LogProbs" -> 5,
  "Model" -> "gpt-3.5-turbo"}]

(*  <|Content->True,FinishReason->stop,Role->Assistant,Model->gpt-3.5-turbo-0125,Timestamp->Fri 2 Aug 2024 13:53:46GMT-4,Usage-><|History->25tokens,Completion->1token|>,CallID->chatcmpl-9rqlGWi31pfcNViuDD4WSuWw5zCC2|> *)
(* note absence of log-prob info *)

However 14.1 does permit the use of RawChat to achieve this goal (and thus is a valid solution):
ServiceExecute["OpenAI", "RawChat", 
   {"messages" -> {<|
       "role" -> "user", 
       "content" -> "Do bears defecate in the forest? Answer only True or False and nothing else."|>},
  "logprobs" -> True,
  "top_logprobs" -> 2,
  "model" -> "gpt-3.5-turbo"}]

(* <|"id" -> "chatcmpl-9rqkioZC2U4NWmNNsnOEtDfhUhCHI", 
 "object" -> "chat.completion", "created" -> 1722621192, 
 "model" -> "gpt-3.5-turbo-0125", 
 "choices" -> {<|"index" -> 0, 
    "message" -> <|"role" -> "assistant", "content" -> "True"|>, 
    "logprobs" -> <|"content" -> {<|"token" -> "True", 
         "logprob" -> -0.000096987, "bytes" -> {84, 114, 117, 101}, 
         "top_logprobs" -> {<|"token" -> "True", 
            "logprob" -> -0.000096987, 
            "bytes" -> {84, 114, 117, 101}|>, <|"token" -> "False", 
            "logprob" -> -9.26222, 
            "bytes" -> {70, 97, 108, 115, 101}|>}|>}|>, 
    "finish_reason" -> "stop"|>}, 
 "usage" -> <|"prompt_tokens" -> 25, "completion_tokens" -> 1, 
   "total_tokens" -> 26|>, "system_fingerprint" -> Null|> *)


One solution is to construct the request manually...or at least rely on Anton Antonov's helper functions to do so...
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/Misc/OpenAIRequest.m"]

OpenAIRequest[
  {"v1", "chat", "completions"},
  <|"model" -> "gpt-3.5-turbo",
   "messages" -> {
     <|"role" -> "user", 
       "content" -> "Do bears defecate in the forest? Answer only True or False and nothing else."|>},
   "temperature" -> 0,
   "max_tokens" -> 2,
   "logprobs" -> True,
   "top_logprobs" -> 2|>];
%[["choices", 1, "logprobs", "content", 1, "top_logprobs"]]

(* 
{<|token->True,logprob->-0.0000482327,bytes->{84,114,117,101}|>,
 <|token->False,logprob->-9.97489,bytes->{70,97,108,115,101}|>}
*)

